# Problem with ParametricPlot

Tags: plotting

I am trying to use the parametricplot to switch the x and y axis, but seems it not working. Also, since ParametricPlot[{w, k1}, {w, 0, 2*10^16}] and
    Plot[k1,{w, 0, 2*10^16}] should be equivalent and yields the same result, why it still not working. Thanks very much for any help.

```
ebp = 9;
hbar = 6.582119*^-16;
wp = ebp/hbar;
ϵi = 1;
ϵinfi = 1;
τ = 3.3*^-14;
ϵc1 = ϵinfi (1 - wp^2/w^2);
ϵc2 = ϵinfi wp^2/(w^3 τ);
ϵcc = ϵc1 + ϵc2 I;
ϵspc = Refine[ComplexExpand[(ϵi + ϵcc)/(ϵi ϵcc)], w > 0 && Element[w, Reals]];
c = 3*^8;
k = w/(c Sqrt[ϵspc]);
k1 = Refine[Re[k], w > 0 && Element[w, Reals]];
ParametricPlot[{k1, w}, {w, 0, 2*10^16}]
ParametricPlot[{w, k1}, {w, 0, 2*10^16}]
Plot[k1,{w, 0, 2*10^16}]
k2 = Im[k];
graph1 = Plot[{k1, k2}, {w, 0, 2*10^16}, PlotRange -> Full];
Show[graph1 /. x_Line :> Reverse[x, 3], PlotRange -> All, AxesLabel -> {"k", "w"}, ImageSize -> Medium, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 0) Browse the [common pitfalls](http://goo.gl/zpsUsd) question 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 2) Read the [faq]! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 3):

```
ParametricPlot[{w, k1 }, {w, 0.1, 2*10^16}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ParametricPlot[{k1, w }, {w, 0.1, 2*10^16}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: Oh, yes. That's what am i missing, Thanks so much.